# Remove diacritic from only one column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem with remove diacritic from only one column in database. Is it possible to remove diacritic from only one column?

I tried:

```
select 'áéíóú' collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS
```

but it is over whole table.

I need :

**Table1**:

```
Column1 Column2 Column n
------------------------
šbook   sbook   
čbook   cbook   
ěbook   ebook
ábook   abook
...     ...
```

Comment: May be this helps.https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/572109/How-to-replace-accented-characters-with-non-accented-ones

Comment: Why can't you use COLLATE inside the SELECT statement: `SELECT Column1, Column1 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS AS Column2 FROM Table1`?

Comment: How Can I write this as UPDATE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `convert()` to `varchar()` with `collate`:

```
update t
 set Column2 = convert(varchar(32),Column1 collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS);

select Column1, Column2
from t;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/FSW95264

returns:

```
+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 |
+---------+---------+
| šbook   | sbook   |
| čbook   | cbook   |
| ěbook   | ebook   |
| ábook   | abook   |
+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE Table1
SET   [Column2]  = @[Column2]
WHERE  [Column2] COLLATE QL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS FROM [dbo].[Table1]